# Django Rest Framework works fine in PATCHing in localhost but fails in homolog environment

Tags: python, django, postgresql, rest, django-rest-framework

I've just deployed my Django/Python application in a homolog environment. The application uses Django Rest Framework to implement `REST`.

Now I'm testing the homolog environment, and having a little problem with a resource that I want to do partial updated. But testing app in `localhost` works fine.

**Localhost:**
I'm using `httpie` to consume API resources. The command below sends a PATCH to an object `experiment` in localhost:

```
http -a lab1:'nep-lab1' PATCH  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/experiments/11/ status='to_be_analysed'
```

and that's all right, the PATCH is made successfully.

**Homolog:**
In homolog environment the same command fails.

```
http -a lab1:'nep-lab1' PATCH  http://myhomologenv.com.br/api/experiments/11/ status='to_be_analysed'
```

Error:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Length: 2065
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 27 Jul 2017 18:48:48 GMT
Server: squid/2.7.STABLE9
Via: 1.0 athena.ime.usp.br:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
X-Cache: MISS from athena.ime.usp.br
X-Cache-Lookup: NONE from athena.ime.usp.br:3128
X-Squid-Error: ERR_INVALID_REQ 0

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved</title>
<style type="text/css"><!-- 
 %l

body
:lang(fa) { direction: rtl; font-size: 100%; font-family: Tahoma, Roya, sans-serif; float: right; }
:lang(he) { direction: rtl; }
 --></style>
</head><body id="ERR_INVALID_REQ">
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p><b>Invalid Request</b> error was encountered while trying to process the request:</p>

<blockquote id="data">
<pre>PATCH /api/experiments/12 HTTP/1.1
Host: portal-dev.numec.prp.usp.br
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json, */*
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.8
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 28
Authorization: Basic bGFiMTpuZXAtbGFiMQ==

{&quot;status&quot;: &quot;to_be_analysed&quot;}</pre>
</blockquote>

<p>Some possible problems are:</p>
<ul>
<li id="missing-method"><p>Missing or unknown request method.</p></li>
<li id="missing-url"><p>Missing URL.</p></li>
<li id="missing-protocol"><p>Missing HTTP Identifier (HTTP/1.0).</p></li>
<li><p>Request is too large.</p></li>
<li><p>Content-Length missing for POST or PUT requests.</p></li>
<li><p>Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.</p></li>
<li><p>HTTP/1.1 <q>Expect:</q> feature is being asked from an HTTP/1.0 software.</p></li>
</ul>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster">webmaster</a>.</p>
<br>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
if ('[unknown method]' != '[unknown method]') document.getElementById('missing-method').style.display = 'none';
if ('[no URL]' != '[no URL]') document.getElementById('missing-url').style.display = 'none';
if ('[unkown protocol]' != '[unknown protocol]') document.getElementById('missing-protocol').style.display = 'none';
</script>

<hr>
<div id="footer">
<p>Generated Thu, 27 Jul 2017 18:48:48 GMT by athena.ime.usp.br (squid/2.7.STABLE9)</p>
<!-- ERR_INVALID_REQ -->
</div>
</body></html>
```

I'm using `DefaultRouter` to make object `url`'s.

More about tools and packages used:
**Localhost:**

- Sqlite3
- Virtual server
- Debian 9

**Homolog:**

- Postgres 9.4.6
- Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
- Debian 8.3

**Both:**

- Django==1.11.2
- djangorestframework==3.6.3
- coreapi==2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

As the response says, please check with your system administrator.
This response is generated from Squid so it doesn't even reach your Django project.